# Code Explanation of how to return an array of structs

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

I was reading a [tutorial on a medium](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-returning-structs-from-public-functions-e78e48efb378) about how to return an array of structs. This is the code they have for doing it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Project
{
    struct Person {
        address addr;
        uint funds;
    }

    Person[] people;

    function getPeople(uint[] indexes)
        public
        returns (address[], uint[])
    {
        address[] memory addrs = new address[](indexes.length);
        uint[]    memory funds = new uint[](indexes.length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            Person storage person = people[indexes[i]];
            addrs[i] = person.addr;
            funds[i] = person.funds;
        }

        return (addrs, funds);
    }
}
```

The `uint[] index` argument however makes no sense to me. Can someone please explain what it is and what it does?

Comment: Do you mean the `uint[] indexes` argument?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. @valkn0t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uint[] indexes` is used to access the data of people located at the indices passed to the function, to build an array of structs to return.

For example: if there were 100 `Person` stored in the contract, and we wanted an array of just the `Person`'s stored at `[1, 2, 3]`, we pass that array as `uint[] indexes` and receive the addresses and funds located at `people[1]`, `people[2]`, and `people[3]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense. What it if I wanted to return every person in people.  [1... people.length] ? Still a newbie to solidity :)

Comment: If you wanted to return the entire array you could simply remove/ignore the argument `uint[] indexes` and loop over `people[]` til `people.length`, putting the addresses and funds into the correct arrays, and returning them like how it's implemented in the code above. Also just to be clear: solidity is simply a Javascript-esque language used to write and compile smart contracts; these questions are more Javascript questions than Solidity. If you have further questions about things like loops and arrays and such, I'd suggest researching Javascript code before Solidity.

Comment: ah! gotcha! I will try that approach. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: I will do that. Very new to javascript as well. Thanks for your help.